# gym_recording does not get imported at all ! I have tried everything

Tags: python, package, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

```
import os
import numpy as np
import gym
from gym import wrappers
from gym_recording.wrappers import Monitor
# import pybullet_envs

ENV_NAME = 'BipedalWalker-v3'
# ENV_NAME = 'HalfCheetahBulletEnv-v0'

class Hp():
    # Hyperparameters
    def __init__(self,
                 nb_steps=1000,
                 episode_length=2000,
                 learning_rate=0.02,
                 num_deltas=16,
                 num_best_deltas=16,
                 noise=0.03,
                 seed=1,
                 env_name='BipedalWalker-v2',
                 record_every=50):

        self.nb_steps = nb_steps
        self.episode_length = episode_length
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.num_deltas = num_deltas
        self.num_best_deltas = num_best_deltas
        assert self.num_best_deltas <= self.num_deltas
        self.noise = noise
        self.seed = seed
        self.env_name = env_name
        self.record_every = record_every


class Normalizer():
    # Normalizes the inputs
    def __init__(self, nb_inputs):
        self.n = np.zeros(nb_inputs)
        self.mean = np.zeros(nb_inputs)
        self.mean_diff = np.zeros(nb_inputs)
        self.var = np.zeros(nb_inputs)

    def observe(self, x):
        self.n += 1.0
        last_mean = self.mean.copy()
        self.mean += (x - self.mean) / self.n
        self.mean_diff += (x - last_mean) * (x - self.mean)
        self.var = (self.mean_diff / self.n).clip(min = 1e-2)

    def normalize(self, inputs):
        obs_mean = self.mean
        obs_std = np.sqrt(self.var)
        return (inputs - obs_mean) / obs_std


class Policy():
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, hp):
        self.theta = np.zeros((output_size, input_size))
        self.hp = hp

    def evaluate(self, input, delta = None, direction = None):
        if direction is None:
            return self.theta.dot(input)
        elif direction == "+":
            return (self.theta + self.hp.noise * delta).dot(input)
        elif direction == "-":
            return (self.theta - self.hp.noise * delta).dot(input)

    def sample_deltas(self):
        return [np.random.randn(*self.theta.shape) for _ in range(self.hp.num_deltas)]

    def update(self, rollouts, sigma_rewards):
        # sigma_rewards is the standard deviation of the rewards
        step = np.zeros(self.theta.shape)
        for r_pos, r_neg, delta in rollouts:
            step += (r_pos - r_neg) * delta
        self.theta += self.hp.learning_rate / (self.hp.num_best_deltas * sigma_rewards) * step


class ArsTrainer():
    def __init__(self,
                 hp=None,
                 input_size=None,
                 output_size=None,
                 normalizer=None,
                 policy=None,
                 monitor_dir=None):

        self.hp = hp or Hp()
        np.random.seed(self.hp.seed)
        self.env = gym.make(self.hp.env_name)
        if monitor_dir is not None:
            should_record = lambda i: self.record_video
            self.env = Monitor(self.env, monitor_dir, video_callable=should_record, force=True)
        self.hp.episode_length = self.env.spec.timestep_limit or self.hp.episode_length
        self.input_size = input_size or self.env.observation_space.shape[0]
        self.output_size = output_size or self.env.action_space.shape[0]
        self.normalizer = normalizer or Normalizer(self.input_size)
        self.policy = policy or Policy(self.input_size, self.output_size, self.hp)
        self.record_video = False

    # Explore the policy on one specific direction and over one episode
    def explore(self, direction=None, delta=None):
        state = self.env.reset()
        done = False
        num_plays = 0.0
        sum_rewards = 0.0
        while not done and num_plays < self.hp.episode_length:
            self.normalizer.observe(state)
            state = self.normalizer.normalize(state)
            action = self.policy.evaluate(state, delta, direction)
            state, reward, done, _ = self.env.step(action)
            reward = max(min(reward, 1), -1)
            sum_rewards += reward
            num_plays += 1
        return sum_rewards

    def train(self):
        for step in range(self.hp.nb_steps):
            # initialize the random noise deltas and the positive/negative rewards
            deltas = self.policy.sample_deltas()
            positive_rewards = [0] * self.hp.num_deltas
            negative_rewards = [0] * self.hp.num_deltas

            # play an episode each with positive deltas and negative deltas, collect rewards
            for k in range(self.hp.num_deltas):
                positive_rewards[k] = self.explore(direction="+", delta=deltas[k])
                negative_rewards[k] = self.explore(direction="-", delta=deltas[k])
                
            # Compute the standard deviation of all rewards
            sigma_rewards = np.array(positive_rewards + negative_rewards).std()

            # Sort the rollouts by the max(r_pos, r_neg) and select the deltas with best rewards
            scores = {k:max(r_pos, r_neg) for k,(r_pos,r_neg) in enumerate(zip(positive_rewards, negative_rewards))}
            order = sorted(scores.keys(), key = lambda x:scores[x], reverse = True)[:self.hp.num_best_deltas]
            rollouts = [(positive_rewards[k], negative_rewards[k], deltas[k]) for k in order]

            # Update the policy
            self.policy.update(rollouts, sigma_rewards)

            # Only record video during evaluation, every n steps
            if step % self.hp.record_every == 0:
                self.record_video = True
            # Play an episode with the new weights and print the score
            reward_evaluation = self.explore()
            print('Step: ', step, 'Reward: ', reward_evaluation)
            self.record_video = False


def mkdir(base, name):
    path = os.path.join(base, name)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    return path

# Main code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    videos_dir = mkdir('.', 'videos')
    monitor_dir = mkdir(videos_dir, ENV_NAME)
    hp = Hp(seed=1946, env_name=ENV_NAME)
    trainer = ArsTrainer(hp=hp, monitor_dir=monitor_dir)
    trainer.train()
```

but when i run the code this error comes

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym_recording'
```

This is my code, I want installed gym_recording using

```
pip install gym_recording
```

and it worked. When I type

```
pip3 show gym-recording
```

it gives

```
Name: gym-recording
Version: 0.0.1
Summary: UNKNOWN
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/snigdh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: boto3, gym
Required-by:
```

I even tried including the code

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/snigdh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages')
```

but it did not work. What should I do? I am stuck. I asked open chat gpt, and tried all the thing it told me to try like but none of it worked. By the way, I am not using a virtual environment, I am doing this in VS studio as a simple project.

Comment: have you installed it globally or in enviroment

Comment: I am not using a environment

Comment: the best way is to make a virtual environment, activate that environment, and install all packages in that environment. if you have multiple works so its better approach to do stuff using virtual environment..

Comment: I tried in it virtual environment too but it still does not work, it shows the same error an if i try pip install gym_recording, it says it is already do requirement already satisfied

Comment: type pip install and check it is install or not using pip
pip show gym_recording

Comment: i have already tried pip show gym_recording and it gave

Comment: ```Name: gym-recording
Version: 0.0.1
Summary: UNKNOWN
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/snigdh/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: boto3, gym
Required-by:```

Comment: can you show me the terminal?

Comment: i cant send picture here

Comment: ok then make virtual environment and activate it and then continue your work

Comment: I have tried it in a virtual environment(its activated) and also without a virtual environment in my virtual machine(xubuntu), both of them say they have gym_recording when typing pip show gym_recording but both of them when importing gym_recording say that module dosent exist.

Comment: guys plz help, somebody